# how to get the dimensions of custom image on storyboard manually

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I added a custom `UIImageView` to a storyboard and got the following dimensions:

[image]

I tried using `CGRectMake(170, 115, 260, 200)` in my code to crop an image but didn't get the same dimensions as the `UIImageView`, but a size considerably smaller than that used in the storyboard. How can I get the exact dimensions for a `CGRect`?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: if you are using Generic storyboard for all the devices is would differ.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara Yes, I am using a generic storyboard. How can I get the dimensions right regardless of the device dimensions?

Comment: @NSologistic use fix height & width constraints.

Comment: @Mikael: I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused between what things look like in storyboard vs on the device. The storyboard only is a representation of a set of rules that will dictate how things will appear on actual devises.

- **If you want the UIImageView to be the same size on all devises** you need to set constraints for height and width
- **If you want the same ratio to prevent your image from distorting** you need to set ratio constraints

You should read this: [ray auto layout tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

In case this does not help, this is how you get the size of a CGRect:

```
CGRect myFrame = [YOUR_VIEW frame];
NSLog(@"height = %f", myFrame.size.height);
NSLog(@"width = %f", myFrame.size.width);
NSLog(@"x = %f", myFrame.origin.x);
NSLog(@"y = %f", myFrame.origin.y);
```

Comment: setting the constant height and width and/or ration constraints didn't work. Basically, I overlayed a rectangle on the view and took a photo (using my custom camera). I want to crop out the overlayed rectangle region from the photo using the `CGRectMake`. How can I convert the storyboard values to pixel values to get the exact region?

Comment: I edited the answer of how you get the size of a frame. Hopefully this helps.